# Making an access plan with openstreetmap

Tags: openstreetmap, cartography

What tool would be best to create an access plan (with directions written on roads, local zooms, etc.) from OpenStreetMap (preferably using the MapQuest Open map)?

[image: example of access plan]

Comment: What's an access plan?

Comment: @Spacedman: I added an example. It could look different, but the idea is there: a tuned map to access a specific place from various routes.

Comment: So you want a fixed, static image, or set of images (region, city, building-level), with some annotation? And is this to go on a web page?

Comment: @Spacedman: I want to generate a map to get to a given place, to be sent/printed in order to tell people how to get to this place.

Answer (score 2):

Grab the images from the web client of whatever map provider you want, then add annotations using a graphics package.

All you need is a screen grab app and Inkscape, if you've not got a license for adobe illustrator..

Make sure you don't violate the terms of service if your map data provider.